# Error: Cannot match any routes in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am lazy loading few modules in my Angular 4 app, with child routes to the lazy loaded module, but I am getting an error as `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order-management/list-view'` when accessing the route.

Here's my main app routing code:

```
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'order-management', loadChildren: './order-management/order-management.module#OrderManagementModule'},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

and here's the routing code for the lazy loaded `OrderManagementModule`:

```
    {path: '', component: OrderManagementComponent, pathMatch: 'full', children: [
        {path: 'list-view', component: ListComponent},
        {path: 'column-view', component: ColumnComponent},
        {path: 'comfy-view', component: ComfyComponent},
        {path: '', redirectTo: '/order-management/list-view', pathMatch: 'full'},
  ]}
```

Assume the code to load each child component in the path `/order-management/SOME_CHILD_COMPONENT` and also redirect `/order-management` path to `/order-management/list-view`. I am not sure, what went wrong here. Please solve this issue.

Comment: Can you remove the `pathMatch: 'full'` from the `OrderManagementComponent` path. Also set the `redirectTo` to `list-view`

Comment: @PierreDuc that worked! But can you please explain, when the `pathMatch: 'full'` is causing the issue.

Comment: I've added an answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the `pathMatch: 'full'` from the first `path` where you already defined a `component: OrderManagementComponent`.

You cannot have a `pathMatch` in combination with a `component`. Perhaps `angular` should have already thrown an error for that. `pathMatch` is used for redirects, which means that if you have a `pathMatch` property in your route, you should have a `redirectTo` as well.

I'll have to dig into the source of the angular router, to see why it would throw this error:

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'order-management/list-view'

But if I have to guess, I think that it sees the `pathMatch` property, and tries to redirect. But redirect to what? There is no `redirectTo` property. My guess is that it tries to some unknown route, maybe with `undefined`, and it will throw an error.